# Magento 2.3.3 Login at checkout not working sometimes

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, cookie

in our Magento when user insert their email at checkout if they already have an account, they are asked to optionally login.

Sometimes when the user login using the correct password, the user is redirected to an empty cart page in which he/she is still logged out.

if the user tried to do the same (logging in from checkout) for the second time in the same browsing session it usually works normally and the user continues the checkout journey, we use the default multi-page checkout.

the issue is intermittent, since sometimes its works from the first time, but sometimes it doesn't.

any advice on how to debug this issue or if its already had a fix?

Comment: Please Update your version Magento 2.4 Instance. This issue is fixed on the latest Magento version.

Comment: Thank you, working on the upgrade